# How to autofill a start and end date where both values are within one cell? Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, auto-form-fill

In Excel 2013, I have 2 dates (start and end of pay week) within 1 cell and want to autofill as follows.

```
02/01/2014 - 08/01/2014
09/01/2014 - 15/01/2014
23/01/2014 - 29/01/2014
16/01/2014 - 22/01/2014
```

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Split the cell (string) into two new columns (as date, text to columns, '-' as seperator), use autofill on both columns. At last concat both columns into a single one with " - " between

Answer (score 0):

Go to cell A1 and enter in your first FROM date. In B1 enter your first TO date. Now do the same thing in A2 and B2 for your next 2 dates. You should now be able to highlight all 4 and drag them down to autofill to the end of the year (or whatever is the final pay period you're looking for).

Now in cell C1 type the following:

```
=TEXT(A1,"m/d/yy")&" - "&TEXT(B1,"m/d/yy")
```

and drag down to the end of your date range.